# How do I define a method which can accept different sequences of arguments?

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, visual-studio

In C#, Python and/or VB.NET, how can I write a method of a class that can accept different sequences of arguments? As an indication, the multiple choices of arguments sequence would be accessible when pressing shift+shift+space in Visual Studio.

Comment: FYI, methods which are identical in name but take different arguments are called *overloaded methods*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to be bit more explicit on method overloading and variable parameter numbers. You can have different methods with the same name in the same `interface`, `class` or `struct` as long as they have a different number of parameters or parameters of different types (or both) in C# and VB. C# example:

```
public int Foo(string s)       // OK, first method
public int Foo(double d)       // OK, different type
public void Foo(double x)      // Error, same parameter type, return
                               // type and parameter name do not matter.
public int Foo(string s, DateTime d)   // OK, diffent number of parameters.
```

In addition, the last parameter can be an array, which represents a varying number of parameters. It must be introduced with the `params` keyword (C#) or the `ParamArray` keyword (VB).

C#

```
public int Foo(string s, params int[] n)
```

VB

```
Function Foo(ByVal s As String, ByVal ParamArray n As Integer()) As Integer
```

You can call it like this, C#

```
int i = Foo("Hello");   
int i = Foo("Hello", 5);   
int i = Foo("Hello", 5, 7);   
int i = Foo("Hello", 5, 7, 13);   
int i = Foo("Hello", new int[] { 2, 4, 6 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create multiple methods with the same name and different parameters(called overloading a method):

```
public int myMethod(String someString){
    //code
}

public int myMethod(int someInt){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can use `*args` (for positional arguments) and `**kwargs` (for named arguments) to catch all the arguments passed to the method:

```
class Example:

    def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print args, kwargs

    def method2(self, arg0, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        print arg0, arg1, arg2, kwargs
```

This gives:

```
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.method(1, 2, 3, key='value')
(1, 2, 3) {'key': 'value'}
>>> e.method(1, 2, key1='value1', key2='value2')
(1, 2) {'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

In `Example` the method `method2` has at least three arguments (`arg0`, `arg1`, and `arg2`) and zero or more keyword argument (`**kwargs`). This means you can call `method2` as follows:

```
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.method2(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3 {}
>>> e.method2(1, 2, 3, key='value')
1 2 3 {'key': 'value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the named and optional arguments feature of .Net 4:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx?ppud=4

```
public void myMethod(object requiredParam, object optionalParam = null, 
                     int optionalInt= 0)
{
}
```

In this method the only parameter that you MUST have is the first.  The other two will be defaulted to the provided values if they aren't provided.

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments are of a different type you could overload the method

Alternatively, you can just pass in a value indicating the sequence of arguments and have logic within the method to treat it accordingly.